# Unauthorized (HTTP 401) R omdbapi

Tags: r

I'm getting an error when I try to access the OMDbAPI (http://www.omdbapi.com/). In addition, when I go to that site and try to manually look up a movie, I get a `Response failed`.

I am trying to run this line:
`find_by_title('Arrival', year_of_release = 2016)` and get this error:
`Error in find_by_title("Arrival", year_of_release = 2016) : Unauthorized (HTTP 401).`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get a key and add it to all your requests now.

OMDb API: http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=key
Poster API: http://img.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&h=600&apikey=key

This is what they had on their site.

```
We are going private!

05/10/17 - New API Keys! Due to some security concerns on how the keys were being distributed I updated the form to email them and also changed the algorithm used, which means your older keys not obtained through email will eventually stop working. 

05/08/17 - Going Private! Please go read the post on the Patreon page about this major change.
```

You have to get an API Key.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So if I understand this correctly the only way that someone can now use the omdbapi is by paying?

Comment: Granted, it looks like it's only $1 per month for 100k requests per day.

Comment: Yes. Then I think it is $5 if you also want posters. In my view, the guy has done a lot of work so he deserves some income.

Answer (score 1):

I used their API for over a year and now it stopped. If you need to perform lots of queries then I think becoming a sponsor to OMDBAPI is a good idea. However I used their API in my little private project. After googling a bit I found another API. Here's the code in PHP perhaps you can do something similar in R:

```
<?php
$imdbID = 'tt2866360';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.rest7.com/v1/movie_info.php?imdb=' . $imdbID));

if (@$data->success !== 1)
{
    die('Failed');
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data->movies[0]);
```

I am not affiliated with this website. But I use this API so can answer a question or two if anyone has.